# onmouseover for element li doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following simple code, but it doesn,t work

```
<ul>
  <li id="one" onmouseover="this.style.background-color='white';">
    <a href="#">home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

could you tell me why.
thanks

### edit:

and how can i also change the color of a tag, onmouseover of li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert hyphens to camelCase when changing properties of the style object in JS.

`backgroundColor`

However, you are trying to solve this problem in the wrong way.

If you really wanted to style the list item on hover, then you probably should be using `li:hover` in your stylesheet. The only downside is that this won't work in IE 6 (although it is just a cosmetic effect on an ancient browser that is increasingly falling in the "Not supported" box).

That said, having a hover effect shouts "You can click now!" at the user — but only the link portion of the list item will do anything when clicked. This means that you should style the `a` element, not the `li` … but style it to fill the list item (and this **will** work in IE6).

[Listamatic has many examples.](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/)

Comment: @David Dorward but how can i style a element to fill the list item, if i want to change color on hover of li, not a?

Comment: `display: block` gets you most of the way there. http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical08.htm for instance.

Comment: @Syom: Didn't want to detract from David's answer by writing my own, but as per your edit, you can apply CSS styles to the `<a>` element using the direct descendant CSS selector: e.g. `li:hover > a { color: black; }`

Answer (score 2):

it'll be `onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='white';"`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use pure CSS for this one?

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Otherwise use gX's and David Dorward's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) or a js framework (like jQuery). whatever:hover has only 3kb or so, so I guess is worth to load it :)

As a side note, I think you should take a look at [this list](http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm) to see how CSS styles are converted to JS.